# Netbeans 7.2 hangs at "Loading Modules..."

Tags: java, startup, netbeans-7, netbeans-plugins

I recently installed Netbeans 7.2 on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS and wanted to add some plugins. I got prompt to install some updates and agreed. Downloading those updates took quite a long time and I had to download some packages manually, but this were probably some issues with my corporate network and proxy. When it finally finished successfully I was prompted to restart IDE and so I did. Startup showed up and I got message that some modules were in wrong versions and they must be disabled. I clicked "disable modules" and then startup hangs informing only "Loading modules...". Tried doing it few times but the result is always the same. Even tried reinstalling IDE but whole process looked the same.

Any ideas how to make it work?

Comment: no answer for this yet? I have the same problem. Netbeans got stuck on loading modules after installing j2me sdk tools